# Subscription with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3, ecommerce, member

I am using Craft Commerce v2 plugin with Craft CMS v3 with one of my site which basically sells kid products.

It's a subscription website and ones some parent subscribe for any kids package, they will charge for a month ( recurring every month ) and then we will send kids package every week for that month.

I am not sure if Craft Commerce is able to handle recurring payments and subscription / membership thing.

Can anyone help me out, what's the possible and best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Commerce 2, currently in beta, does support subscriptions, but right now it's only when using the [Commerce Stripe payment gateway plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe).

If you're using a different payment gateway that supports subscriptions, you'll have to write a custom Craft/Commerce plugin and you can use the Commerce Stripe one as a starting point.

The relevant Commerce subscription documentation lives here: 
 https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/subscriptions.html